# Подсчитать колличество групп?

Tags: mysql

Этим запросом выводится список групп.

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( p.xfields, 'label|', -1 ) ,  '||', 1 ) as xf_label, count(*) as count
                   FROM dle_post p
                   WHERE LOCATE('label|',p.xfields)>0
                   GROUP BY xf_label
                   ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 0,{$limit}
");
```

Как вывести количество этих групп?

Comment: `select count(1) from (ваш-запрос) X`

Comment: Хотя учитывая ваш group by может быть проще `select count(distinct xf_label) from dle_post where LOCATE('label|',p.xfields)>0`

Comment: Можно подробнее

Comment: Эммм ... что подробнее ? последний запрос вообще должен выполнится как написан, а первый ... вместо "ваш-запрос" пишите полный текст своего запроса, который привели в вопросе

Comment: Первый вариант пробовал, вообще ничего не вывел, можете полностью код написать?

Comment: Вы его в самом mysql попробуйте, он либо что то выдаст либо напишет ошибку. И если будет ошибка от нее и надо будет отталкиваться